# Cypress: How to mock key board (CTRL/SHIFT) actions

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image]

As shown in picture i have these elements in  a tree.If i press CTRL in KEY BOARD and click on these text-i can select multiple elements  and it will give links to do some actions.Using cypress is there any way to achieve this ? i know if it is select, i can use select -in my case these are just 'ul'.Also i know while tying text we have options, is there any options in cypress to mock this Key board action while click or selecting elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using this syntax:

```
cy.get('body')
  .type('{alt}', {release: false})
cy.get('.heading')
  .click()
cy.get('.tooltip__header')
  .should('contain', 'Translate')
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
cy.get('body')
  .type('{ctrl}', {release: false})
cy.get('Sugar CSP Segmentation')
  .click()
cy.get('Health & Welness Segments')
  .click()
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative syntax, which reads more intuitively IMO, is to pass the `ctrlKey` option ([documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Arguments)):

```
cy.get('Sugar CSP Segmentation').click()
cy.get('Health & Welness Segments').click({ctrlKey: true})
```