# How to hold shift and use arrow keys in Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have an issue when using the Cypress type() command in the way I want.

**My objective**

I want to be able to select and delete text in a textfield. I want this done via holding the shift key, pressing the right arrow key multiple times and then pressing the delete key.

**My attempt**

```js
//hold shift and use right arrow
cy.type('{shift}{rightarrow}'.repeat(10));
//press delete
cy.type('{del}');
```

Comment: Have you tried `cy.type('{shift}{rightarrow}'.repeat(10))`?

Comment: @JuanMendes yes even with that it seems to still not be selecting the text like i expect. I will change my original attempt as cypress docs explain modifiers are released after each type command

Comment: `.repeat(10)` where is this coming from. I could see nothing in the docs?

Comment: @AlapanDas String.repeat is a native javascript command I believe, to repeat the string. This example i tested works fine with right arrow alone

Comment: If you just use `{shift}{rightarrow}` without the repeat, then does this work once ?

Comment: My last suggestion was very incorrect. Here are two things to try: `cy.type('{shift}' + {rightarrow}'.repeat(10), {release: false})` or just plain `for (const i = 0; i < 10; i++) cy.type({shift}{rightarrow}))`

Comment: @AlapanDas im afraid even a single usage without repeat doesn't work either

Comment: @JuanMendes, the issue isnt with the repeat, but moreso the pressdown and release it seems. Ive tried your release: false suggestion and im afraid that doesnt seem to do it either.

Comment: I also suggested a simple for loop

Comment: Maybe we should backtrack a bit to figure out what is the test intention and see if the selecting and deleting specific text is the best approach, because `cy.type()` will only append to the existing string.

Answer (score 3):

As per the available information instead of `repeat`, you can use the `Cypress._.times` loadash method. This will run the entire type command 10 times.

```js
Cypress._.times(10, () => {
  cy.type('{shift}{rightarrow}')
})
```

Comment: Never heard of a Cypress lodash method... What is that?

Comment: @JuanMendes I have updated the wording of my answer. About `Cypress._` loadash You can read about it from here - https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_.

Comment: @AlapanDas I have also tried this and it doesnt work, im afraid the issue isnt with the repeat, but moreso the shift not activating when it should

Comment: @taran Please share your html to debug more.

Answer (score 1):

The  element needs focus before applying arrow keys,

```js
cy.get('#myinput')
  .focus()
  .type(Cypress._.repeat('{shift}{rightarrow}', 5))
  .type('{del}')
```

This gets the cursor moving within the the element's text, but unfortunately  does not extend the selection, so `{del}` only removes one element.

You can use an internal input method instead of `{shift}{rightarrow}`, if this suits your test

```js
cy.get('#myinput')
  .focus()
  .then($el => $el[0].setSelectionRange(0, 5))
  .type('{del}')
```

To clear completely,

```js
cy.get('#myinput')
  .clear()          // types {selectall}{del}
```

Comment: just to clarify, the repeat isnt the issue. A single cy.type('{shift}{rightarrow}') doesn't highlight a single character like you'd expect it would

Comment: Ok, got it. Sounds like there's an event that's not firing, you probably want `.trigger('keypress',  {keyCode: 39})`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes looking, I had success with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55020253/412908) of using `{release:false}` with the modifier.  Here's some example code for selecting and deleting the two lines above:

```
    cy.get("body").type("{shift}", {release: false});
    cy.get("body").type("{upArrow}{upArrow}");
    cy.get("body").type("{shift}");
    cy.get("body").type("{backspace}");
```